# Positioned element is off when on Safari`

Tags: html, css, safari, css-position

I have a button with arrows that is supposed to appear and move down  when moused over.  On Chrome and Firefox it works fine but when I open it up on Safari the arrows are too low- they aren't positioned correctly. I have heard about people specifying "top" and :left" but that doesn't seem to work for me. I don't know why this is but it seems to be due to the position: relative.
Code:

```
<a class="details" href="#scroll"> <span class="details__border--bottom">More Details</span>
</a>
    
    <div class="top-portion__arrows">
        <span class="top-portion__arrows--hide"></span> 
        <span class="top-portion__arrows--hide"></span>
        <span class="top-portion__arrows--hide"></span>
    </div>



   a.details {
    border: 2.5px solid white;
    padding: 8px 62px;
    padding-top: 11px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.75rem;
    background-color: rgba(214, 128, 0, 0.45);
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
            transform: translateX(-50%);
    left: 50%;
    top: 5%;
    z-index: 1;
    display: inline-block;  
}


a.details:hover,
a.details:focus {
    background-color: rgba(231, 147, 21, 0.25);
    -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in;
    -o-transition: .5s ease-in;
    transition: .5s ease-in;
}
a.details:hover,
a.details:focus {
    border: 3.5px solid white;
    -webkit-transition: .15s;
    -o-transition: .15s;
    transition: .15s;
}
a.details:active {
    background-color: rgba(247, 195, 100, 0.75);
    -webkit-transition: .15s;
    -o-transition: .15s;
    transition: .15s;
}

.details__border--bottom {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 2px 0px 4px;
    margin: 0px 8px 0px;
    position: relative;
}


 .details__border--bottom:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0px;
    border-bottom: 2.5px solid white;
    bottom: 2px;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleX(0);
    transform: scaleX(0);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.45s ease-in-out;
    transition: -webkit-transform 0.45s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: transform 0.45s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 0.45s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 0.45s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 0.45s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover .details__border--bottom:before,
a:focus  .details__border--bottom:before {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
}

.top-portion__arrows {
    position: relative;
    width: 0%;
    top: 10%;
    left: 51.5%;
    
}

.top-portion__arrows .top-portion__arrows--hide {
    opacity: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid white;
    border-right: 3px solid white;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
            transform: rotate(45deg);
    margin: -85px;
}

a.details:hover + .top-portion__arrows .top-portion__arrows--hide,
a.details:focus + .top-portion__arrows .top-portion__arrows--hide {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-animation: animate .65s ease;
            animation: animate .65s ease;
}

.top-portion__arrows .top-portion__arrows--hide:hover .details__border--full,
.top-portion__arrows .top-portion__arrows--hide:focus .details__border--full {
    border: 2.5px solid white;
    -webkit-transition: .2s ease-in;
    -o-transition: .2s ease-in;
    transition: .2s ease-in;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate {
    0%{
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-10px,-10px);
                transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-10px,-10px);
    }
    50%{
        opacity: .5;
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(0px,0px);
                transform: rotate(45deg) translate(0px,0px);
    }
}

@keyframes animate {
    0%{
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-10px,-10px);
                transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-10px,-10px);
    }
    50%{
        opacity: .5;
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(0px,0px);
                transform: rotate(45deg) translate(0px,0px);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect whether a user is browsing on safari with some javascript and then if they are browsing on safari, style the buttons a certain way by changing the margin-left and margin-top. Here is the code to detect whether the user is on safari:

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(); 
if (ua.indexOf('safari') != -1) { 
  if (ua.indexOf('chrome') > -1) {
    alert("chrome") // Chrome
  } else {
    alert("safari") // Safari
  }
}
```

Edit: Your full code:

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(); 
if (ua.indexOf('safari') != -1) { 
  if (ua.indexOf('chrome') > -1) {
  } else {
document.getElementById("btn1").style.marginTop = "80%";  }
}
```

Comment: Well, I;m not too keen on JS, but I put it in my code and now I get an alert when its being opened on chrome. How do I changed the margins for just safari only?

Comment: You can get take the button by it's id and style is using JavaScript. First assign an id to the button. Add id="btn1" to the button. Then inside of then take out the alert if browsing on safari and replace that code with this line: document.getElementById("btn1").style.marginTop = "80%"; You can edit the percentage for better results and make it fit to your needs. I edited the answer to include the entire code. Make sure to add the id to the button for the code to work.

Comment: So it works but the problem is when I enter responsive design mode on my mac and go to 1920 x 1080 the arrows are too high. I am not sure how to fix that.

Comment: Thats a differnet problem altogether. With this problem, you need to style the margin-top of the buttons depending on the screen width. You can do this with css.  W3 schools has an excellent tutorial on how you can acheive this. Here is the link: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp Lets say you assign an id of btn1 to your button. Use #btn1 { inside the media queries and inside the #btn1 use the margin-top property to style the buttons.

Comment: It's also off on my Ipad when I use the Simulators in Xcode.  It does this every time.  It looks perfectly normal on my emulator in Chrome but when it shows up on an apple device its usually off.  the position property isn't responsive IMO

Comment: An apple device should run smoothly just like a regular browser on your computer exept for the screen width. Your issue should be fixed by adding a media quesry for ipad and detecting whether the user is on ipday and if they are change the margin properties.  Here is the code for detecting if the user is on ipad. @media only screen and (device-width: 768px) {
style here}